# Elasticsearch Get only result which distinc value

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to exclude result which have a same meta LIKE :

> SELECT DISCTINCT IDParent FROM MyDocument

I can get only aggs with cardinnality but i would like to exclude them

```
{
"size" : 0,
"aggs" : {
    "distinct_colors" : {
        "cardinality" : {
          "field" : "color",
          "precision_threshold" : 100 
        }
    }
}
}
```

I want to exclude result which have the same value for a specific meta

If i have two results with

```
Name = testname
```

I would like to get only one of them

Comment: Please specify with the help of an example what you want to exclude?

Comment: Is it more understandable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [top hits aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html):

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "top-tags": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "name",
                "size": 0
            },
            "aggs": {
                "top_tag_hits": {
                    "top_hits": {
                       "size" : 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This should bucket all the results using values from `field` and return 1 document per bucket. Which document, that you can control using the sort parameter.